# GridView и сказка о кривом клике

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, activity

У меня проблема с GridView.
Вот исходное фото:

[image]

А вот после того как я нажал:

[image]

Суть такая, что когда я нажимаю, то должна загораться желтым цветом белая область в самом Item, то есть вокруг картинки и текста, а он загорается в Item, но за ним почему-то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ВОПРОС ЗАКРЫТ, добавил строчку:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent">
```

Comment: Собственно это я и предлагал вторым пунктом.

Comment: А почему не работает STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM, мне надо чтобы ITEM Был с отступом со всех сторон на 50?

Comment: @xTIGRx, про это ничего не знаю. )

Comment: Ну, в принципе Marginom обошлось. )

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего дело в отсутствии отступов (margin) в лэйауте отдельной ячейки.

Второй вариант - отступы есть, но фон лэйаута, на коем лежит картинка - непрозрачен.

Comment: @xTIGRx, сложно мне вас понять.

Comment: @xTIGRx, фон прозрачен по умолчанию. Если вы ему не зададите какого-либо значения, он будет прозрачен.

И таки попробуйте margins лэйауту каждой ячейки указать.

Comment: Маргин и так 20p указан.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, http://pastebin.com/Qzxgiy3h. отдельный лайэот который используется в адаптере